# Absolute distance from various points in O(n)

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, distance, dynamic-programming

I am stuck in question. The part of the question requires to calculate sum of absolute distance of a point from various points.
|x - x1| + |x - x2| + |x - x3| + |x - x4| ....

I have to calculate this distance in O(n) for every point while iterating in array for eg:

**array = { 3,5,4,7,5}**
  *sum of distance from previous points*

```
dis[0] = 0;
dis[1] = |3-5| = 2
dis[2] = |3-4| + |5-4| = 2
dis[3] = |3-7| + |5-7| + |4-7| = 9
dis[4] = |3-5| + |5-5| + |4-5| + |7-5| = 5
```

Can anyone suggest the algo to do this ?
Algorithm for less than O(n^2) will be appreciated ( not necessarily O(n)).

Code for O(n^2)

```
REP(i,n){
   LL ans = 0;
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
      ans= ans + abs(a[i]-a[j])
   dis[i]=ans;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the code you have written so far.

Comment: Is it O(n) space or time?

Comment: @H2CO3 I have written an O(n^2) code!

Comment: @akash You should still include it, or preferably a high-level description of it.

Comment: I don't think I even understand what exactly you try to do. Looking at the dis[i] examples, it seems that, for element i, you calculate the sum of distances of this point i to those 0, 1, ..., i-1 (call this d(i)); then sum d(i) from 1 to n-1 - and this is to take O(n). Is that what you mean? I find "various points" pretty confusing; based on your description alone I would have thought you calculate each point's distance to each other point. then sum these distances up.

Comment: sorry for the ambigous xplaination , i need to calculate this d[i] in O(1), so total array d in O(n)

Comment: What are constraints on xi's?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja it is 10^9

Comment: @jfk916 2 + |4-7| ! = 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O(n log n) algorithm is possible.

Assume we had a datastructure for a list of integers which supported:

```
Insert(x)
SumGreater(x)
SumLesser(x)

Insert(x) inserts x into the list.
SumGreater(x) gives the sum of all elements greater than x, which are in the list.
SumLesser(x) gives the sum of elements < x.
NumGreater(x) gives the number of all elements greater than x.
NumLesser(x) gives the number of all elements < x.
```

Using balanced binary trees, with cumulative sub-tree sums and sub-tree counts stored in the nodes, we can implement each operation in O(log n) time.

To use this structure for your question.

Walk the array left to right, and When you encounter a new element x

You query the already inserted numbers for `SumGreater(x) = G and SumLesser(x) = L and NumGreater(x) = n_G and NumLesser(x) = n_L`

The value for x would be `(G - n_G*x) + (n_L*x-L)`.

Then you insert x and continue.

Comment: You can even make this closer to O(n) by using a signature sort and a table of sums of the first N numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Is O(n) even possible? - If the size of your output is 1/2 * n^2, how can you populate it in O(n) time?

Comment: The size of the output is `n`! But great observation.

Comment: I got the question now, I think dynamic programming (caching and reusing previously calculated results) is the way to solve it. Your question already points in that direction, for example: